# Ribenboim’s remark on posets.

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

I am reading a book of Ribenboim “Rings and Modules” and I am trying to understand his remark on p.37:

Remark. In any partially ordered set $X$ (e.g., the set of all submodules of a module M, ordered by inclusion) the following assertions are equivalent:

(i) Every strictly increasing (decreasing) sequence of elements of X is finite.

(ii) Every nonempty subset of $X$ has a maximal (minimal) element.

I tried (i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii) : Let $Y \subset X$ be a non-empty subset of X. Let C be a non-empty increasing chain in Y. We may suppose that C is strictly increasing (because, for instance, if there is a subset {a, b, c} with a = b = c, then we can write {a} instead). By hypothesis, C is finite, therefore C has a upper bound $y \in Y$, so $c \leq y$ for all $c \in C$ (in fact, $y \in C$ because C is finite).
By Zorn’s lemma, Y has a maximal element $m \in Y$.

But now I want to show (ii) $\Rightarrow$ (i).

I started with: let $S \subset X$ be a strictly increasing sequence of elements of $X$. Suppose $S$ is non-finite.
But I am stuck now. Can anybody please help me to finish this proof ?

Comment: you don't need Zorn's Lemma to prove this equivalence

Comment: @amrsa Well, you need $\mathrm{DC}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I think you ought to be more careful in your proof that $(i) \implies (ii)$.

Let $X$ be a nonempty subset of your poset. What's your (precise) justification that you can assume $X$ to be an increasing sequence?

Here is what I would do: Suppose $X$ does not have a maximal element. Consider $(X; \prec)$, where $\prec$ is the strict partial order associated to your poset. Since $X$ does not have a maximal element there is for every $x \in X$ some $y \in X$ such that $x \prec y$. Using dependent choice there is hence a function $f \colon \mathbb N \to X$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$
$$
x_n \prec x_{n+1}.
$$
But now $(x_n \mid n \in \mathbb N)$ is a strictly increasing sequence. Contradiction!

$(ii) \implies (i)$. This is easier: If $(x_n \mid n \in \mathbb N)$ is an infinite, strictly increasing sequence then the set $X = \{x_n \mid n \in \mathbb N \}$ doesn't have a maximum. (It may have an upper bound but it certainly hasn't a maximal element.) But that's a contradiction right away.

Comment: I had never heard about DC before. Looked at it now in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice) and your use of it and realised I'm used to somehow using it without statement. Actually, I was about to submit a proof which was the same as yours, except that using some naive approach to justify that sequence instead of using DC.

Comment: @amrsa It's pretty common among mathematicians to use some form of choice without actually realizing that they do so (justifying it intuitively by some other, non-formal means).

Comment: @Stefan Mesken. Thank you for your answer. I am still working on it but I have a few questions.

Comment: @Stefan Mesken. Thank you for your answer. I am still working on it, but I have a few questions. (I) In the proof $(i) \Rightarrow (ii)$, where did you use the given assertion “Every strictly increasing sequence of elements of $X$ is finite”? (II) I did try not justify that $X$ is an increasing sequence, I just took a (totally ordered) chain in $X$ as it is usual to do when applying Zorn’s Lemma. (III) What is “dependent choice” and how do I apply it? (IV) amrsa said: I do not have to use Zorn’ Lemma, but is it wrong to use it?

Comment: @Steenis (I) In $i \implies ii$ I used it to derive a contradiction -- the infinite sequence $f$ that I constructed. (II) Oh, I misread your post. Yeah, your argument is fine as is. (III) [DC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice) (IV) No, it's not wrong to use it. In fact: You need some form of choice (Zorn's Lemma is a form of choice). You could have gotten away with slightly less (DC) but that's likely not of interest to you or your prof.

Comment: @Stefan Mesken. I understand your answer and I understand the application of the DC (axiom of dependent choice). I don’t remember ever using the DC. Maybe I used it unknowingly?  Is the DC, like the AC, independent of the ZF-axioms? I could not find that in the Wikipedia-page. Since I am retired, my prof is retired too, I hope. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Steenis |Sorry. My default assumption on this site is that I'm talking to young college students. No offense intended. |Yes, $\mathrm{DC}$ is independent of $\mathrm{ZF}$ and it follows from $\mathrm{AC}$ (relative to $\mathrm{ZF}$). | Since $\mathrm{ZFC} \vDash \mathrm{DC}$, it's likely that at times where you used $\mathrm{AC}$, you could have gotten away with the strictly weaker principle of dependent choice. Therefore it's likely that you have indeed unwittingly used dependent choice before.